# Tensor product isomorphic to its factor

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $p,$ $r$ be primes, $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ of all fractions $\frac{n}{q}$ for which $p\nmid q$. If $A$ is a finite abelian $r$-group then why

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\cong A, \qquad p=r?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know anything about localizations? $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the multiplicatively closed subset $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z}$. Now you can use the fact that localization commutes with tensor products,i.e, $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z} \bigotimes A$ = $\mathbb{Z} \bigotimes S^{-1}A$ = $S^{-1}A$ = $A$, as $A$ is an abelian-$p$ group.

For the last equality, use the structure theorem of abelian groups to break $A$ into smaller pieces, and then observe that localization commutes with finite product. What happens when you localize $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ at $S$ ? You get $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ only, as all the elements are anyway units.

Comment: could you explain a bit more the equation chain

$S^{-1}\mathbb{Z}\otimes A=S^{-1}A=A$?

Comment: Edited. Sorry that details are missing. Lemme reach home, then I'll properly write it down in case it's still not clear.

Comment: Did you figure out the details ?

Comment: Yes, took some time, but thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One should really point out the intuitive reason: Tensoring an abelian group with $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ means that you allow dividing by numbers co-prime to $p$.

But in an abelian $p$-group, multiplication with a number co-prime to $p$ is an isomorphism, hence we can already divide by such numbers. So tensoring does not change anything.